# Is it safe to manually recreate a jar file to change just a properties file inside

Tags: java, jar, zip

I've got this .jar file with a Java Application inside (For Oracle SOA Policies). I just needed to change a properties file inside to change an endpoint URL.
Is it safe to turn the .jar file into a .zip file, change the .properties (not a Java class, the .properties does not need to be decompiled), then zip it again and trough the extension name, turn it back to a .jar file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say - *Yes*, you can do such trick, if you, for instance, are on production system and do not have access to any IDE for rebuilding `jar`. This is essentially ok to do so, because jar is really ZIP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.JAR files are built on the ZIP file format and have the .jar file extension.Just do not modify or change unless it is really required.You will need to extract the jar via a WinZip/Winrar or any other software.Then modify the things you need to.Then put it back to the archive.It is safe to the extent that you do not modify the vital classes/properties

Comment: I did that. But strangely, the sizes of the new jar files are lower (15-20 kb lower each). The only thing I did was renaming the endpoint. After that, I zipped the file and manually turned the extension to .jar

Comment: If you have changed only that I dont think it will be an issue.try using it..it will definately work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your case it is safe. It would however not work on a signed jar.